# Selenium Alert Box Java

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, alert

I have a more general question without source examples.

I have - until now - three Selenium/Java tasks running with Jenkins. All of them have alert boxes which handeld usually correct. But sometimes, I get the error, what the expected text not appeared or that the alert box doesn't exist. The alert text in the different Selenium/Java tasks is the same!

Is it possible, I can't look the whole time on the screen, what sometimes the alert box of - for example Selenium/Java task 1 - closes also the alert box of an other Selenium/Java task 2 or 3, which appears at the same time?

If so - how can I make sure, that only the right one is closed?

Comment: could you add som id's to those alert boxes and every task close only the related boxes no?

Comment: Hi cralfaro

I am not the programmer of the web site, I just wrote the programs to monitor the sites. So, no I have no option to add id's.

Comment: Then you will have to inspect all those alerts and find some difference to recognize which one you should close, or if you know the order of appearance, you could find all in an array and close the one you need by index

Comment: It's perhaps an Chrome Driver iussue. I found this one here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1486 and an other link, which I until not found again, that tells, with Chrom Driver Version 2.22.2 the problem should be solved. I test this now...

Answer (score 1):

1) If you run your tests at the same time (parallel) you have to use threads, then webdriver will close the right one AlertBox ([link](https://www.guru99.com/sessions-parallel-run-and-dependency-in-selenium.html) or [link](http://seleniumautomationhelper.blogspot.com/2014/02/initializing-webdriver-object-as-thread.html))

2) If you run your tests not at the same time you can do screenshot ([link](https://www.guru99.com/take-screenshot-selenium-webdriver.html)) and copy innerHTML of whole page in selenium driver ([link](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/23701/how-to-save-a-copy-of-web-page-dom-using-selenium-webdriver-and-java-c)) when something goes wrong and analyze what exactly happened in that case.
You of course can do screenshot and copy innerHTML of whole page when you run your tests parallel.